# Where do iOS Apps store their persistent keychain data when run on an M1 Mac?

Tags: ios, keychain, apple-silicon, swift

iOS apps can persist data between uninstalls as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911434/will-items-in-ios-keychain-survive-app-uninstall-and-reinstall)

If an iOS app is run on a Mac, where would this data live? Is it accessible by the keychain viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test with some code I have in one of my apps using [keychain wrapper](https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper):

```
extension UIDevice {
    nonisolated static var udid: String {
        let key = "persistentUdid"
        if let uuid = keychain.string(forKey: key) {
            return uuid
        }
        let uuid = UUID().uuidString.lowercased()
        keychain.set(uuid, forKey: key)
        return uuid
    }
}

let keychain = {
    let chain = KeychainWrapper.standard
    //   chain.removeAllKeys()
    return chain
}()
```

I can indeed find this key in keychain access (bundle ID is just random)

[image: keychain access]